# if == condition does not output expected results in django template

Tags: python, django, conditional-statements, operator-keyword

A beginner here.
Apologies if this is a very basic question.

I am working with the Django template using python. My if conditional doesn't seem to work.
Here I assumed a basic string comparison between a and be should yield "Very Happy," the second block. It doesn't. I output to display in my browser window and the result is always "Very Frustrating."
I never get "Very Happy" the 2nd block.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
a = "test4"
b = "test5"

{% if a == b %}
<strong>Very Frustrating</strong>
{% else %}
<strong>Very Happy</strong>
{% endif %}
```

My actual code will have a and b be variable imports (in order to ensure only logged in users can do certain things). Like so:
a = {{logged_user}}
b = {{clicked_username}}

I put in the simplest test values for a and b (2 different strings) to isolate the issue for clarity.
I can provide the actual code. But I figured if this doesn't work as expected with simple strings as is, this is where the problem is.

Thank you for your time.

---

Actual code below.
The Goal is to have the edit button be visible only for posts of the user(i.e. a user can only edit their own posts).
`{% if post.username == logged_user %}` doesn't show any edit button (even for cases where the post.username & logged_username appear to be the same). I substituted the strings in my simplified example above so as to check if it was to do with data types etc.

Whereas if i change to `{% if post.username != logged_user %}` it does(not what i want though). It appears the expression as written below is simply evaluating to false, as such nothing is shown.

```
<div class="post-section">
    {% for post in all_posts %}
            <div class="each_post">
                 <a href="{% url 'profile' post.username %}" class="poster_name">{{ post.username }}</a>
                 <div class="post_post" id="{{post.id}}">{{post.post}}</div>
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                {% if post.username == logged_user %}
                <button class="edit_button">Edit</button>
                {% else %}
                {% endif %}
                {% endif %}
                <div id="content_edit"></div>
                 <p class="post_date">{{post.timestamp}}</p>
                 <p class="like_link" id="lk{{post.id}}">{{post.like_count}}</p>
            </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

My view block

```
@csrf_exempt
def post(request):
    posts = Post.objects.order_by("-timestamp").all()
    paginator = Paginator(posts, 10)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    all_posts = paginator.get_page(page)
    if request.method == "POST":

        new_entry = request.POST["user_post"]
        new_post = Post.objects.create(username=User.objects.get(username=request.session["user"]), post=new_entry)
        context = {
            "logged_user": request.session["user"],
            "all_posts": all_posts, 
        }
        return render(request, "network/main.html", context)

    else:

        context = {
            "logged_user": request.session["user"],
            "all_posts": all_posts,
        }

        return render(request, "network/main.html", context)
```

applicable Class Model

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    num_followers = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    num_following = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.username}"

class Post(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    like_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.post}"

    def serialize(self):
        return {
            "id": self.id,
            "post": self.post,
            "timestamp": self.timestamp.strftime("%m %d %Y, %I:%M %p")
        }
```

Conclusion.
The simplified example I started out with
"test4" & "test5" are the same data type, strings, as such should not have any issue with comparing different data types.
I feel if i can understand what went wrong in the simplified example i can extrapolate to my actual problem. Thanks again everyone.

Comment: Are you sure that `logged_user` and `clicked_username` are what you expect? Do any of them contain spaces at the beginning or end? Are the upper- and lower-casing the same in both strings?

Comment: They both print out as the same user. Albeit with different types (as one is from a class instance). Regardless, though shouldn't the "test5" & "test4" cases work then. As they are just strings with very clear formatting, no spaces etc.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for the tips. Yes it was a data type issue (I didn't realize it mattered that much in such comparisons). I slugified my object variable inorder to convert to string like so.

'''{% if post.username|slugify == logged_user %}'''

It works now!

Answer (score 0):

Preliminary we can start with checking types of the two variables

```
 a = {{logged_user}} //(as per naming seems like it would be a User class object)
 b = {{clicked_username}} //(as per naming seems like it would be a string)
```

Check There data types and if you find so then it has to be a.username getting compared with b

Comment: "logged_user" is gotten from request.session["user"] and is of type <class str>.  post.username is of type <class 'network.models.User'>.However If the issue is of comparing different types and not some other issue, shouldn't the "test5" & "test4" cases work in the simplified 1st example above as they are both strings etc? Thank you.